# Update automaticRepliesSetting via PowerShell with Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-exchange

I am trying to update automaticRepliesSetting via PowerShell for my Exchange Online users.

I know that I can do it with the Graph API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/automaticrepliessetting?view=graph-rest-1.0) via HTTP.

Is it also possible to update these settings with the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK?

I have installed the Microsoft.Graph Module but do not find a cmdlet for it...

Using Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration is not an option as I am connecting to Graph via an App Registration with certificate authentication and restrictive permissions...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it also possible to update these settings with the Microsoft Graph
> PowerShell SDK?

We don't have any predefined cmdlet in Microsoft Graph PowerShell module to update `automaticRepliesSetting`  for a particular user.

If you want update automatic replies setting you have use this PowerShell cmdlet `Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration` which is a part of [Exchange PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration?view=exchange-ps) Module.

Since we don't have any Microsoft Graph PowerShell cmdlet , you can use `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell, invoke the [Update mailbox user setting rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as explained in this [blog](https://www.techguy.at/set-out-of-office-reply-with-powershell-and-ms-graph-api/)(sending an out-of-office email by  invoking MS graph api using PowerShell).